# Does looping occurs at the same speed for all systems?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, loops, mono

Does looping in C# occur at the same speed for all systems. If not, how can I control a looping speed to make the experience consistent on all platforms?

Comment: You can slow a loop using various methods, but this is only viable under certain circumstances. More details about your situation would help us to provide answers.

Comment: For the record, this question has nothing to do with his business requirements. He needs to poll for USB device added.

Comment: Hehe, don't poll.  Nobody told him about WM_DEVICECHANGE yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set a minimum time for the time taken to go around a loop, like this:

```
for(int i= 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
   ... rest of your code...
}
```

The sleep call will take a minimum of 100ms (you cannot say what the maximum will be), so your loop wil take at least 1 second to run 10 iterations.

Bear in mind that it's counter to the normal way of Windows programming to sleep on your user-interface thread, but this might be useful to you for a quick hack.

Answer (score 7):

You can never depend on the speed of a loop. Although all existing compilers strive to make loops as efficient as possible and so they probably produce very similar results (given enough development time), the compilers are not the only think influencing this.

And even leaving everything else aside, different machines have different performance. No two machines will yield the exact same speed for a loop. In fact, even starting the program twice on the same machine will yield slightly different performances. It depends on what other programs are running, how the CPU is feeling today and whether or not the moon is shining.

Comment: you inspired me: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6196/is-it-possible-that-the-current-phase-of-the-moon-could-have-an-effect-on-electro

Comment: @shogun: haha. As long as you don’t wait for the psychology SE to ask about the psychoses of CPUs …

Answer (score 6):

No, loops do not occur the same in all systems. There are so many factors to this question that it can not be appreciable answered without code.

This is a simple loop:

```
int j;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  j = j + i;
}
```

this loop is too simple, it's merely a pair of load, add, store operations, with a jump and a compare. This will be only a few microops and will be really fast. However, the speed of those microops will be dependent on the processor. If the processor can do one microop in 1 billionth of a second (roughly one gigahertz) then the loop will take approximately 6 * 100 microops (this is all rough estimation, there are so many factors involved that I'm only going for approximation) or 6 * 100 billionths of a second, or slightly less than one millionth of a second. For the entire loop. You can barely measure this with most operating system functions.

I wanted to demonstrate the speed of the looping. I referenced above a processor of 1 billion microops per second. Now consider a processor that can do 4 billion microops per second. That processor would be four times faster (roughly) than the first processor. And we didn't change the code.

Does this answer the question?

For those who want to mention that the compiler might loop unroll this, ignore that for the sake of the learning.

Answer (score 2):

One way of controlling this is by using the `Stopwatch` to control when you do your logic. See this example code:

```
int noofrunspersecond = 30;
long ticks1 = 0;
long ticks2 = 0;
double interval = (double)Stopwatch.Frequency / noofrunspersecond;
while (true) {
  ticks2 = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
  if (ticks2 >= ticks1 + interval) {
    ticks1 = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
    //perform your logic here
  }
  Thread.Sleep(1);
}
```

This will make sure that that the logic is performed at given intervals as long as the system can keep up, so if you try to execute 100 times per second, depending on the logic performed the system might not manage to perform that logic 100 times a second. In other cases this should work just fine.

This kind of logic is good for getting smooth animations that will not speed up or slow down on different systems for example.

Comment: Care to elaborate since you obviously know better?